# How to prevent android quick reply notification from being stuck in loading?

Tags: android, notifications, android-7.0-nougat

My app uses the Android N's new quick-reply feature to quickly take notes from a fixed notification, without having the user to open an activity.

However, I would like the notification to be reset to its initial state after the user sends the quick reply message, without having to dismiss the notification.

Here is my code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ? createChannel() : "").setSmallIcon(android.R.mipmap.sym_def_app_icon).setContentTitle("My Awesome App").setContentText("Doing some work...").setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            android.support.v4.app.RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(BookmarkCreatorReceiver.TXT_REPLY).setLabel("Reply").build();

            Intent replyIntent = new Intent(this, BookmarkCreatorReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent replyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, replyIntent, 0);

            NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email, "Bookmark", replyPendingIntent).addRemoteInput(remoteInput).build();
            NotificationCompat.Action actionQuick = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email, "Quick", replyPendingIntent).build();
            builder.addAction(action);
            builder.addAction(actionQuick);
        }

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

The problem is that once the user sends a message and the Broadcast receiver is called, the notification stays in the loading state like this:

[image]

How can I remove the loading message, without having to discard the notification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [Notifications in Android N blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/notifications-in-android-n.html#directreply):

> After you’ve processed the text, **you must update the notification** by calling notify() with the same id and tag (if used). This is the trigger which hides the Direct Reply UI and should be used as a technique to confirm to the user that their reply was received and processed correctly.

Also note:

> For most templates, this should involve using the new [setRemoteInputHistory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder#setRemoteInputHistory(java.lang.CharSequence[])) method which appends the reply to the bottom of the notification.

This ensures that users see the text they entered was properly handled.

Comment: I tried calling `notify()`, but it gives me an `IllegalMonitorStateException`, saying 'object not locked by thread before notify()'

Comment: How can I call the notify() method on my notification? Calling it on the UI thread produces the same issue.

Comment: They mean [NotificationManager.notify()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification)) using the same `NOTIFICATION_ID` and `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much!

Comment: Where should .notify be called again, exactly? I don't know where to handle the reply event.

Comment: @Josh - when building a `RemoteInput`, you attach it to an action that takes a `PendingIntent` - it is that Service/BroadcastReceiver that receives the events and where you should be doing your processing of the input, updating the notification included.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zg4v9G-lku8 
This video explains, what is happening when you get stuck in loading

Comment: What's App on android could benefit from this trick.